# How can I fill a std::unorderd_map concurrently?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, unordered-map

I need to fill a `std::unordered_map<int,T>` with about 100 entries. Those are expensive to construct and I would like to use OpenMP to do that concurrently:

```
unordered_map<int, T> mapWithTs;

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) // dynamic because T constructs in some unpredictable time.
for(int i=0; i<100; ++i)
{
  mapWithTs.emplace(i, {i}) // calls the constructor T(i)
}
```

I read that the map will rehash and then iterators will no longer be valid. What must I do to make this work?

Further, what would the concurrency solution with the standard library look like?

Comment: Expensive to construct but are they cheap to move? Could each thread create its own vector full then one thread move those vector objects into the map?

Comment: You would create several threads, each populating its own map, then merge the maps (in a single thread).

Comment: You just need to synchronize (mutual exclusion) the access to the map. I don't know how to do that synchronization with OpenMP, but presumably you do. If not, just consult the documentation.

Comment: @ Galik, you mentioned what I planed first but then was wondering if there is a way to do it directly. e.g. suppress rehashing or something like that. Right now I think the best way to do it is to default construct an "empty" T and then overwrite it or make some T::doTheExpensivePart() method.

Comment: Why not use a data structure which is already designed for parallelism, such as TBB's concurrent unordered map https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506171 ? You can use this with OpenMP, though you might want to look at TBB for all your parallelism needs too. (FWIW I work for Intel, bit not on TBB, and, in any case TBB is BSD-style licensed :-)).

Answer (score 2):

In case these expensive to construct instances are help by reference, i.e. by shared_ptr, raw pointer, &c., I suggest letting each thread create its own, stack-local map, in a step canonically also called "map", and then combine them all in a single thread in a step canonically called "reduce".

This is called the "map-reduce" algorithm.

"map" is the usual name of a function that applies a function to all elements of a collection

"reduce" is the usual name of a function that combines all elements in a collection to a single value by calling a function with the current intermediate result and each element

hence the name :)

Comment: One thing to be careful of is using a "map" operation that implicitly uses heap memory through `new`, `malloc`, or similar.  Most implementations provide a single heap for all threads, so the use of heap memory could result in contention and locking similar to explicitly using a shared map with locks.

Comment: Do you mean when it runs low? Or are the heaps of the JVM, GNU libc++, BSD libc++ surprisingly terribly inefficient when it comes to concurrent allocations?

Comment: *Do you mean when it runs low? Or are the heaps of the JVM, GNU libc++, BSD libc++ surprisingly terribly inefficient when it comes to concurrent allocations?*  Any of those.  Either of those.  It depends on the heap implementation and the memory usage pattern.  In my experience, multithread-aware heaps tend to work very well - most of the time. But I've seen usage patterns that reduce such heap implementations to effectively single-thread an application.  It's just something to be aware of, if you benchmark expecting a 6X speedup from running 8 threads and see no speedup at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing this out, this may turn out to be a really valuable piece of knowledge, just like monitoring a unix or linux machine's system load, which I only recently found out is a BIG thing :D

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Galik and yeoman, it is essential to make moving of your objects a cheap operation. If it already is (construction is heavy, but moving is cheap), then you are fine. Otherwise you should put your objects in-to a `uniq_ptr`'s. After this rehash will be a cheap operation too (yes, rehash takes linear time, but it is 0(1) amortized complexity). So you don't need to worry about rehash.

The next thing is filling the map. You are working with it from several threads so you have to ensure that no more than one thread works with it simultaneously. You need something like `#pragma omp critical` or std::mutex. And here comes important part: if you use `emplace` like you do it now, then the heavy T constructor will be executed under critical section which kills whole idea of parallelization. So in this particular case you would prefer creating object T beforehand, then entering critical section and **moving** the object in-to a hashmap.

If construction of the T is really a heavy operation (it takes much longer, then inserting a value in-to a unordered_map), then that will be all. You won't get performance gain by making per thread lists and inserting them in-to the map. Otherwise, yeoman's answer can give you additional benefits by the cost of increasing complexity of your code.